# Woocommerce Category/SubCategory/Product 404 Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hoping you can help me with this problem. Im having an issue with some Products in Subcategories 404'ing when going to there Product Page. But the odd thing i havent been able to find on google is only *some* of them doing it.

Example

SKU: Product1 -- Categories: Category 1

SKU: Product2 --Categories: Category 2, SubCategory 1

SKU: Product3 -- Categories: Category 2, Subcategory 1

SKU: Product4 -- Categories: Category 2, SubCategory 1

Product1, Product2, Product4 **will display.**
With URL: /shop/category/subcategory/product

Product3 **will not display**
With URL: /shop/category/subcategory/product

**HOWEVER**
With URL: /shop/category/product it will display.

Anyone know how to fix this? As on the shop page, it will redirect to the subcategory url string if you click it.

What i have tried:
Flushing Permalinks
Changing and Resetting Permalinks
Removing the Part, Re-Adding the Part and manually adding the categories
Changing category and moving it back

Suggestions would be helpful, as im now on a deadline and cant seem to work this out.

**Update::**

I can now narrow down which products will throw a 404. Any product that was originally uploaded in bulk by Excel that had a format incorrect and pushed to the RH side of the cell instead of the LH Side will 404 error. Now removing and fixing this and re-uploading doesnt help. Nor does manually re-adding the partnumber. Out of 400~ product SKU's 17 of them had this error and all 404 and wont fix.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to Refresh / Flush WordPress Permalinks?

- Step 1: In the WordPress admin area, go to “Settings > Permalinks”
- Step 2: Click “Save Changes”
- Step 3: Permalinks and rewrite rules are flushed.

As they are imported using a manual tool, this may be the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have tried flushing the permalinks. Changing them and resetting them. Doesnt seem to fix the certain products.